# Why is iconField ignored for branch nodes with the Flex Tree component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I'm using the iconField property of the Flex Tree to dynamically set the icon that a node should use. This works fine for leaf nodes but for branch nodes it doesn't seem to respect my iconField and instead just shows the default folder node.

Here's a simple repro:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Embed("assets/icon1.png")]
        public var icon1:Class;

        [Embed("assets/icon2.png")]
        public var icon2:Class;
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:XML id="dp">
    <node label="Sales" icon="icon1">
        <node label="East" icon="icon2"/>
        <node label="West" icon="icon2"/>
    </node>
</mx:XML>

<mx:Tree dataProvider="{dp}" labelField="@label" iconField="@icon"
    width="100%" height="100%" />

</mx:Application>
```

What happens is that icon2 shows for the East and West nodes but icon1 doesn't show for the Sales node. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with an iconFunction... This looks like it does what you want:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/15/creating-a-custom-icon-function-on-a-flex-tree-control/

Comment: Hmm, yep that works. Weird that iconFunction works but iconField doesn't. In any case, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see. susichan was right with iconFunction:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Embed("icon1.png")]
        public var icon1:Class;

        [Embed("icon2.png")]
        public var icon2:Class;

        [Embed("icon3.png")]
        public var icon3:Class;

        private function setIcons(item:Object):Class {
            var iconClass:Class;
            var classType:String = XML(item).attribute("icon");
            if(classType!="")
                return this[classType];
            else
                return null;
        }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:XML id="dp">
    <root>
            <node label="Sales" icon="icon1">
                <node label="East" icon="icon3"/>
                <node label="West" icon="icon3"/>
            </node>
            <node label="Non-Sales" icon="icon2">
                <node label="East" icon="icon3"/>
                <node label="West" icon="icon3"/>
            </node>
    </root>
</mx:XML>

<mx:Tree dataProvider="{dp.node}" labelField="@label" iconField="@icon"
         iconFunction="setIcons" showRoot="true"
         width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost!
You need to set the folderOpenIcon and folderClosedIcon like so:

```
<mx:Tree dataProvider="{dp}" labelField="@label" iconField="@icon"
         folderOpenIcon="{icon3}"
         folderClosedIcon="{icon4}"
         width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Comment: Yeah but what I'm trying to do is have different folder icons for different nodes in the tree. In my case they aren't actually folders at all. Instead they represent different objects with parent-child relationships.